# Pandas: Get an if statement/.loc to return the index for that row

Tags: python, if-statement, pandas, dataframe

I've got a dataframe with 2 columns and I'm adding a 3rd.

I want the 3rd column to be dependant on the value of the 2nd either returning a set answer or the corresponding index for that row.

An example the database is below:

```
print (df)
            Amount      Percentage
Country      
Belgium      20           .0952
France       50           .2380
Germany      60           .2857
UK           80           .3809
```

Now I want my new third column to say 'Other' if the percentage is below 25% and to say the name of the country if the percentage is above 25%. So this is what I've written:

```
df.['Country']='Other')
df.loc[df['percentage']>0.25, 'Country']=df.index
```

Unfortunately my output doesn't give the equivalent index; it just gives the index in order:

```
 print (df)
            Amount      Percentage      Country
Country      
Belgium      20           .0952         Other
France       50           .2380         Other
Germany      60           .2857         Belgium
UK           80           .3809         France
```

Obviously I want to see Germany across from Germany and UK across from UK. 
How can I get it to give me the index which is in the same row as the number which trips the threshold in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Country'] = np.where(df['Percentage']>0.25, df.index, 'Other')
print df
         Amount  Percentage  Country
Country                             
Belgium      20      0.0952    Other
France       50      0.2380    Other
Germany      60      0.2857  Germany
UK           80      0.3809       UK
```

Or create `Series` from `index` by [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html):

```
df['Country']='Other'
df.loc[df['Percentage']>0.25, 'Country']=df.index.to_series()
print df
         Amount  Percentage  Country
Country                             
Belgium      20      0.0952    Other
France       50      0.2380    Other
Germany      60      0.2857  Germany
UK           80      0.3809       UK
```

Comment: The `numpy.where` method has given the result I was looking for

Comment: Can you tell me why that method works and my original one didn't?
They both specify df.index as the output?

Comment: Hard question - I was first suprised that doest work - `df.loc[df['Percentage']>0.25, 'Country']=df.index`. If index is convert to `Series` - it work as my second solution. Maybe it is bug.

Answer (score 1):

To use the method you were trying to implement:

```
df['Country'] = 'Other'
df.loc[df['Percentage'] > 0.25, 'Country'] = df.loc[df['Percentage'] > 0.25].index

>>> df
         Amount  Percentage  Country
Country                             
Belgium      20      0.0952    Other
France       50      0.2380    Other
Germany      60      0.2857  Germany
UK           80      0.3809       UK
```

Because the filter is the same on both sides, it is often best to use a mask on large datasets so that you only do the comparison once:

```
mask = df['Percentage'] > 0.25
df.loc[mask, 'Country'] = df.loc[mask].index

# Delete the mask once finished with it to save memory if needed.
del mask
```

Comment: This works but returns `NaN` for all results below the threshold. Where in your code do I specify that these should be called 'Other'?

Comment: On the first line.  I first set the entire column to `Other`, then use `loc` to to set those above the threshold to the `Country` index.